# Windows 10 automatically deleting WiFi credential fields?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, wifi-configuration, automatic-update, bug-tracking

Lately I've been running into quite a few situations with users having an issue where on Windows 10, when entering credentials for a WiFi connection, the fields are automatically deleted before they can be completed. This will happen in both the username field as well as the password field at random, if entered quickly enough you can sometimes establish a connection.

Initially I thought it was just a stuck key, or some new exploit or malware, and then I started to see the pattern of users telling me they recently just had a big update in which requires a reboot (Possibly Creators? Have yet to pinpoint which one it is).

I have seen this issue persist through fresh installs and driver reinstallations and have yet to come up with concrete reasoning for this issue. Google searches yielded only one identical situation posted 2 years ago by someone on Reddit with no conclusion.

My best guess is there is a faulty update within Windows 10 that causes this bug, can anyone provide any input or advice on this?

Edit: This is being seen in a PEAP authenticated wireless environment, where users are dialing in to a Radius server. (Campus/University)

Comment: It's very unlikely this is a issue with 1703 Windows 10 based on the fact more people would have this issue

Comment: You're right, which makes me wonder if it's an issue with our network or authenticaion server(s). But then again it's a very small percentage of users with this issue

Comment: Still many people have this issue. I've experienced it on every wifi-capable machine I used. No clue. No fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to resolve this issue following these steps:

Right-click Start>Windows Powershell(admin). Copy and paste below command:

```
Get-ScheduledTask | foreach { If (([xml](Export-ScheduledTask
-TaskName $_.TaskName -TaskPath $_.TaskPath)).GetElementsByTagName("LogonType").'#text' -eq "S4U") { $_.TaskName } }
```

Note the app names you get as an output.
Disable the apps you noted by running the command in the task scheduler. (For example, HP Customer participation utility task, Carbonite, etc). Explanation below:

- Search for Task Scheduler in the start menu.
- Locate the task in the Window(HP Customer participation/Carbonite).
- Right-click the task and choose Disable.

Restart your PC and your logins would be retained.

Sources:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1069383#c90
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/systemwide-password-amnesia-v2004-build-19041173/232381f8-e2c6-4e8a-b01c-712fceb0e39e

Comment: That doesn’t sound like the problem the OP describes: The input field lost its value before it could be confirmed.